# How can I add a keyboard shortcut to launch a program?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

On Windows, I can create keyboard shortcuts that launch a program by linking to the program or command and adding a shortcut to the link — here's the [how-to](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-keyboard-shortcuts-open-programs#1TC=windows-7) I follow.

Anyway, how can I set the same up on elementary OS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, open system settings and click keyboard:

[image]

Chose Custom, in the sidebar

[image]

Click the + button

[image]

Enter your command

[image]

Click "Disabled", then press your chosen shortcut and it will show up:

[image]

[image]

Finally, you have to log out and back in for the short cuts to be active.

Comment: “you have to log out and back in for the short cuts to be active” Huh, that's surprising. It shouldn't be the case, normally shortcuts are activated immediately.

Comment: @Gilles Yeah, I was surprised too but: https://imgur.com/04iDClZ. Ubuntu doesn't require it either strangely.

Comment: Yes, i can confirm that i need to logout and re-login to take effect ..

Comment: In Juno distro.

Re-login are not anylonger required. ;)