# How can I view the desktop?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, desktop

Right now I have to minimize all windows one by one to get to the desktop. Is there a way to directly view the desktop?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I personally like to use `Hot corners` to show the desktop.

To do this, first install [devilspie](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/DevilsPie?action=show&redirect=DevilsPie) with:

```
sudo apt-get install devilspie
```

Then create a script file with:

```
io.elementary.code ~/minimize.ds
```

(or some other text editor) and inside that file paste the following content:

```
(if
    (begin
        (not(is(application_name) "wingpanel")))
(if
    (begin
        (not(is(application_name) "plank")))
(begin
    (minimize)
    (quit))
))
```

save and exit the text editor.

Then open `Preferences/Desktop/Hot corners`, select `Personalized order` for one of the corners and in the `Execute custom command` text box paste the following:

```
devilspie /home/<user>/minimize.ds
```

Replace `<user>` with your user name, so it looks like this (I've selected the bottom right corner):

[image]

After that, moving the mouse to that corner should show you the desktop.

Comment: Gabriel, this one works like a charm, and the best parts no need to logout and re-login, just setup and instanly activated :)

Comment: (No one downvoted the answer so far) Which command? This one `devilspie /home/<user>/minimize.ds`? It simple executes the script `minimize.ds`.

Comment: @Tim, sorry i choose this answer, because this is command  too, see thats executed custom command from hot corner :) Anyway, thanks a lot for all respons 

Cheers

Comment: @Tim not sure if there's anything inherently better with my answer, I haven't tried yours. Both require installing an extra package, although yours is apparently capable of restoring the windows back to their previous positions whereas mine is not. I'll give your answer a try.

Comment: This method does not work as expected, it also hides the plank and wingpanel.

Comment: @VladPop it used to work 4 years ago, not sure anymore

Comment: Hey @Gabriel, managed to get it working! Had to instruct devilspie to ignore wingpanel and plank. (if
    (begin
        (not(is(application_name) "wingpanel")))
(if
    (begin
        (not(is(application_name) "plank")))
(begin
    (minimize)
    (quit))
))

Answer (score 13):

SuperKey + Right/Left might be the easiest if your more of the casual user and are not fully using all the workspaces all the time. This will let you view the desktop.

Comment: This is probably going to be the simplest answer, to be honest. Just moving to a clean workspace makes the most sense.

Comment: I disagree. Minimizing all windows is a completely different task than changing to a different workspace.

Comment: @Gabriel Well, he is asking to view the desktop not minimize every window.

Comment: @Kultom the original question did: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/revisions/396/1. I see now that it has been edited by Tim and changed its meaning. Not the first time he does this.

Comment: @Gabriel Ahh, right.

Comment: @Gabriel The original question was asking to view the desktop - his current solution was to minimise all windows. Just because he was asking that doesn't make a solution that minimises all windows correct - it's the XY problem again. @Kultom +1`

Comment: @Tim I could've just as easily edited the original question so that there was no trace of the word "desktop" in it (easier even, removing the words "Show Desktop"). You decided to edit it so that it was aimed at what *you* thought should be aimed.

Comment: @Gabriel I aimed it at what I thought best suited the real question he was asking - based on him accepting your answer. I really can't see the issue - he was asking an XY problem question, I got it down to the Y - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @Tim the problem is that just because *you* think the issue is Y, it does not make it true. Other people can see it differently and your trigger-happy editing ends up making things more confusing.

Comment: @Gabriel  we can go back to chat to discuss more if you wish? Note that this is his original question title - `What Is Command To Show Desktop` - well the question is still asking that.

Comment: @Tim there's no need. I've already said to you at the chat room that you need to slow your editing down. You've currently made 168 edits for a total of 144 questions, that is: you've made more edits than questions made by *all* users. You can take that advise or leave it.

Comment: @Gabriel I'm not taking the advice because there is no evidence I've done any more than 1 bad edit. Also, I've edited less than half the posts here - 48%.

Comment: And no, the original question title was `What Is Command To Show Desktop or Minimize All Windows?` as the link I provided above shows. Furthermore, there was *no mention* of the "desktop" in the body of the question. Do as you wish.

Answer (score 12):

You can put the 'Desktop' docket to Plank (the dock application).

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> click on the dock and select *Preferences* from the menu. In the *Docklets* tab you can find *Desktop*, just drag-and-drop it to the dock application.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

First, install `wmctrl`:

```
sudo apt-get install wmctrl
```

The command to show the desktop is the following:

```
wmctrl -k on
```

And to hide desktop (restore all windows) use

```
wmctrl -k off
```

[You can add them to a keyboard shortcut,](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/369/how-can-i-add-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-launch-a-program) or a hot corner - like [@Gabriel suggested](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/439/3).

Comment: Whats mistake Tim?

Comment: Its usually best (and the polite thing to do, in my personal view) to always leave a comment after you downvote a question/answer. Otherwise the user who wrote that question/answer is left wondering what they did wrong, like Tim right now, and nothing can be improved.

Comment: I'm not down voted your answer :) cheers

Comment: @Tim What does "hide desktop" mean? Ie: this command: `wmctrl -k off`. What does it do?

Comment: @Gabriel it's hard to see the effect because if you unminimise the terminal, it doesn't work. Try this: `wmctrl -k on ; sleep 3; wmctrl -k off`.

Answer (score 1):

I use devilspie like in Gabriel's answer, only I like to be able to restore my windows with the same script, so my devilspie script looks like:

```
(begin
  (if (matches (window_property "_NET_WM_STATE") "_NET_WM_STATE_HIDDEN")
  (begin
  (unminimize)
  (quit)
  )
  (begin 
  (minimize)
  (quit)
  )
  )
  (quit)
  )
```

Everything else is the same as Gabriel's answer.

The only problem is it does not keep my windows in the same order when it restores them.

Answer (score 1):

Install Windows Management control or wmctrl:
`sudo apt install wmctrl`

now, typing the following command in the terminal will show the desktop:
`wmctrl -k on`

That is OK, but it is easier with a keyboard shortcut.

- Open System Settings->Keyboard (or search keyboard in Applications for Loki 0.4 Elementary OS and possibly other distributions)
- Go to 'Shortcuts tab
- Go to 'Custom'
- Click the '+' and type `wmctrl -k on` and 'Enter'
- The shortcut will show is 'Disabled' on the right
- Click on 'Disabled' and click on the shortcut you like for example the 'Windows' button + D, also known as 'Super + D'
  [image]
- Try it: click you shortcut. You should see the desktop

That is it. You are done.

Note: this answer is basically the same as [Alex](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users/12813/alexandre-cavalcante)'s [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/9206/how-to-add-show-desktop-icon-in-elementary-os/15618#15618), I just added more detailed steps (and tried to +1 his, but not enough reputation :)

Answer (score 0):

I have done a bash script which uses Xwindow utilities such as xwininfo, xdotool and wmctrl.
All details and full Code of the script at
http://fpkanarias.blogspot.com.es/2017/12/elementary-os-script-para-mostrar.html