# Workspace Switch Hot Corner

Tags: settings, hot-corners, shell

I'm trying to make my two bottom corners switch between workspaces. The solution I had in mind was to create a custom script which would switch between workspaces based on the argument you pass into it.

For my script, I had to install:
`sudo apt-get install wmctrl`

And my script is this (which works btw):

```
work=`wmctrl -d` | grep '*' | grep -o '^[0-9]'
if [[ $1 == "left" ]]; then
  wmctrl -s $((work - 1))
else
  wmctrl -s $((work + 1))
fi
```

I then realized that you can only have one custom command (˃̣̣̥᷄⌓˂̣̣̥᷅ ) ... So I can't place `left` and `right` into the arguments for my script.

Did anyone find a way to get hot corners working this way?

Comment: I have a problem with the script of the cuestion it only moves to the window 1. The line: work=`wmctrl -d` | grep '*' | grep -o '^[0-9]' always return 0 on the variable work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

There is a way and it is actually has been explained in I believe /org/pantheon/desktop/behavior which is seems like settings area that we can access with dconf-editor (or you can see .xml version of it at /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.pantheon.desktop.gala.gschema.xml)

It says;

> If you just put a single command, it will be used for every hotcorner
>   assigned to 'custom-command'. If you instead use the pattern
>   'hotcorner-topleft:command;;hotcorner-bottomright:command' the
>   specific commands will be used per hotcorner. Possible identifiers are
>   'hotcorner-[topleft; topright; bottomleft; bottomright]' followed by a
>   ':' and then the command. ';;' is used as delimiter between command
>   defintions.

So I am using a devilspie command for minimizing all windows as you can find from here [How can I view the desktop?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/396/how-can-i-view-the-desktop)
which requires for me to write :

```
devilspie /home/[user]/minimize.ds
```

at Custom Command are of System-Settings / Desktop / Hot Corners.

Also I have to choose bottom-right (my choice) hot corner as Execute Custom Command right.

However, as in your case if I want to use a custom command at bottom-left hot corner e.g. firefox, I have to change my custom code as:

```
hotcorner-bottomleft:firefox;;hotcorner-bottomright:devilspie /home/[user]/minimize.ds
```

after that simply choosing both bottom corners as Execute Custom Command will be enough to solve your problem.

So if your `left` argument code is at `/home/[user]/left.sh` and if your `right` argument code is at `/home/[user]/right.sh`.

```
hotcorner-bottomleft:/home/[user]/left.sh;;hotcorner-bottomright:/home/[user]/right.sh
```

should solve it.

P.S.: This answer was for assuming you wanted to create two different custom script for each left and right arguments and use them in different corners.