# How to add "Show Desktop" icon in elementary OS?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, desktop, show-desktop, hot-corners

I have installed nautilus to enable desktop icons in **elementary OS Loki**. It works fine but is there any way to add a button that can I use to click and show desktop? Like the ones in **Windows** at right bottom corner?

Is there any command that I can write in `Custom Command` box in Hot Corners settings?

Comment: For a solution using `Hot corners`, see here: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/439/9

Comment: Is there any way to to show the desktop, at first, and later on when the desktop is showed again the windows I covered? Microsoft Windows behavior like

Answer (score 11):

There are two easy options.

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + right click on plank and go to preferences. There is a show desktop docklet.
2. Hot corner solution. Install wmctrl

`sudo apt install wmctrl`

Then you can use `wmctrl -k on` in the custom command box.

Comment: This is not a command that you can quickly toggle. But it works for hiding all windows. Showing again...not so much.

Answer (score 3):

I came looking for a solution to showing the desktop in a single key press and the solution of mapping `wmctrl -k on` to <kbd>SUPER</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> got the job done. Quite handy if you have a really funky conky monitoring configuration running on the desktop.

Note that the above seems to be a half solution though.

If you want to restore the windows you were working on afterwards then you need another keypress for `wmctrl -k off` to restore the applications. I mapped mine to <kbd>SUPER</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> for ease of memory.

Works like a charm.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Install Windows Management control or wmctrl:
`sudo apt install wmctrl`

now, typing the following command in the terminal will show the desktop:
`wmctrl -k on`

That is OK, but it is easier with a keyboard shortcut.

- Open System Settings->Keyboard (or search keyboard in Applications for Loki 0.4 Elementary OS and possibly other distributions)
- Go to 'Shortcuts tab
- Go to 'Custom'
- Click the '+' and type `wmctrl -k on` and 'Enter'
- The shortcut will show is 'Disabled' on the right
- Click on 'Disabled' and click on the shortcut you like for example the 'Windows' button + D, also known as 'Super + D'
  [image]
- Try it: click you shortcut. You should see the desktop

That is it. You are done.

Note: this answer is basically the same as [Alex](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users/12813/alexandre-cavalcante)'s above, I just added more detailed steps (and tried to +1 his, but not enough reputation :)

Comment: I created an account here solely to upvote this complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's an "elementary" Solution for it (pun intended)

- Keep pressed <kbd>CTRL</kbd>
- Right Click anywhere over [plank](/questions/tagged/plank)
- Click on Preferences
- Click on `Docklets`
  [image]
- Drag the `Desktop` icon into [plank](/questions/tagged/plank)
- Profit

---

`Docklets` in Spanish was translated as `Agregados`, a really bad translation must say. Better to keep it as `Docklets`

Answer (score -1):

First install wmctrl:

```
sudo apt install wmctrl
```

Then go to Keyboard -> Shortcuts and click on the last option "Custom". Add a new command by clicking on the "+" on the bottom of the window. 
Insert the command:

```
wmctrl -k on
```

First, it will be displayed as "Disable", all you have to do is set the shortcut you want you. In my case, I've set "super+d"
[image]