# How do I create a toggle custom command shortcut to "show desktop" and "hide desktop"? Combine two shortcuts that view / hide desktop into one

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, command-line

Notice this guys reply here: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/401 - how do I compress / combine into a single shortcut?

By using the `wmctrl` app, we can show / hide desktop in Elementary OS. How do I create a custom command shortcut that'll use same hotkey, to trigger both commands?

1. `wmctrl -k on`
2. `wmctrl -k off`

It would be a beautiful thing if I could just use SUPER + D to trigger toggle commands.

[image: compress shortcut and combine into one...]

I noticed there is an available docklet, i'd really just like to use the "desktop docklet" and keybind that specific docklet to a hotkey. Any ideas?

https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/17753

---

Here is location for `Launcher=docklet://desktop` in file explorer:  `/home/phenom/.config/plank/dock1/launchers/` but when I double click, i try to copy / paste that into terminal, nothing works.. so i reckon it doesn't work in shortcut either.

Maybe I can create a script to run that plank docklet and assign shortuct?

Comment: I am kind of confused, I can use "Supper" + "D" and it shows desktop and pressing again bring me my working tab. What create another shortcut?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this will help.

- Please go to system settings, and click keyboard.
- After that click on the Shortcuts tab and select custom.
- Now please click the "+" icon and paste this `/usr/bin/com.github.spheras.desktopfolder show-desktop` in the command field and click on Disabled to assign shortcut.
- Here, press any combination you like to add and you are good to go.