# Just installed DevilSpie created a hotcorner and the dock disappear everytime I use it

Tags: plank, hot-corners, show-desktop

Just installed DevilSpie according to this topic:

[How can I view the desktop?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/396/how-can-i-view-the-desktop)

The problem is, every time I hit the hot corner, plank disappears. How can I use the specific commands listed in there without minimizing Plank or panel?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell devilspie to ignore plank and wingpanel. In the minimize.ds file you should have something like:

```
(if
     (begin
        (not(is(application_name) "wingpanel")))
(if
    (begin
        (not(is(application_name) "plank")))
(begin
    (minimize)
    (quit))
))
```

EDIT: I also updated the instructions in [How can I view the desktop?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/396/how-can-i-view-the-desktop), it is quite a nifty feature and I think it should be available in elementary OS by default.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works like a charm.

Comment: @Bento Excellent! And remember, on StackExchange, we love upvoting useful answers and marking the question as answered if  your issue is solved. This way, users feel more encouraged to contribute.