# Is there some plugin or app to add hotkeys to noise music player?

Tags: release-freya, music

My laptop doesn't have multimedia keyboard so I want to know if there's some way to have hotkeys for next, previous song in noise music player?

I'm using elementary freya.

Answer (score 1):

You can control noise with the following cmd:

`dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Noise /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.XXX`

For `XXX` you can put Play, Pause, PlayPause, Next, Previous or Stop

Here you see how you configure a shortcut:
https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/370/37